# Сжать изображения используя библиотеку

Tags: java, android

В сети нашел библиотеку [Compressor](https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor).

В `gradle` все подключил и столкнулся с такой проблемой, а точнее непониманием как реализовать:

Открываю галерею

```
switch (itemId) {
    case R.id.action_1:
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_PHOTO_FOR_AVATAR);
        break;
```

Обрабатываю полученное изображение:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case PICK_PHOTO_FOR_AVATAR:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                InputStream imageStream = null;
                try {
                    imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
            }
    }
```

Как дальше использовать эти функции?:

```
  compressedImageFile = Compressor.getDefault(this).compressToFile(actualImageFile);
    Compress Image File to Bitmap

    compressedImageBitmap = Compressor.getDefault(this).compressToBitmap(actualImageFile);
    I want custom Compressor!

    compressedImage = new Compressor.Builder(this)
                .setMaxWidth(640)
                .setMaxHeight(480)
                .setQuality(75)
                .setCompressFormat(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP)
                .setDestinationDirectoryPath(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                  Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath())
                .build()
                .compressToFile(actualImage);
```

т.е я не понимаю, как мое выбранное изображение прогнать через эту библиотеку, как передать точнее.

**UPDATE:**

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case PICK_PHOTO_FOR_AVATAR:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (data == null) {
                    showError("Failed to open picture!");
                    return;
                }
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                InputStream imageStream = null;
                try {
                    imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                Bitmap compressedImageBitmap = Compressor.getDefault(this).compressToBitmap(yourSelectedImage);


            }

    }

}
```

**КРАСНЫМ ПОДЧЕРКИВАЕТ:**

```
yourSelectedImage -Error:(291, 97) error: incompatible types: Bitmap cannot be converted to File
```

Comment: Одним словом, ваш метод принимает File

Answer (score 1):

В методе onActivityResult Вы получили bitmao yourSelectedImage. Ее передаете в `compressedImageBitmap = Compressor.getDefault(this).compressToBitmap(yourSelectedImage);`

compressedImageBitmap - это и будет Ваш сжатый файл.

Comment: `compressedImageBitmap` это что?File или экземпляр класса

Comment: Если писать так,то: `File compressedImageBitmap = Compressor.getDefault(this).compressToBitmap(yourSelectedImage);`
`Error:(239, 103) error: incompatible types: Bitmap cannot be converted to File`

Comment: что не так делаю?

Comment: compressedImageBitmap это bitmap, а не file

Comment: @ pavel163
обновил шапку темы